# Find the $x$ : $(12x-1)(6x-1)(4x-1)(3x-1)=5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find the $x$ :
>
> $$(12x-1)(6x-1)(4x-1)(3x-1)=5$$

My Try :

$$3x-1=t\\ 3x=t+1\\$$

So we have :

$$(t+1)(t+1)(\dfrac{4(t+1)}{3}-1)(t)=\dfrac58$$

$$(t+1)^2(\dfrac{4(t+1)}{3}-1)(t)=\dfrac58$$

Now what ?

Answer (score 6):

multiply both sides by 24 as

$$\left( {12x - 1} \right)\left( {12x - 2} \right)\left( {12x - 3} \right)\left( {12x - 4} \right) = 120,$$

let $a = 12x - 1,$

$$\begin{gathered}
  a\left( {a - 1} \right)\left( {a - 2} \right)\left( {a - 3} \right) = 120, \hfill \\
  \left( {{a^2} - 3a} \right)\left( {{a^2} - 3a + 2} \right) + 1 = 121, \hfill \\
  {\left( {{a^2} - 3a} \right)^2} + 2\left( {{a^2} - 3a} \right) + 1 = 121 \Rightarrow  \hfill \\
  {\left( {{a^2} - 3a + 1} \right)^2} = 121 \Rightarrow \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  {a^2} - 3a = 10 \to a =  - 2,5 \hfill \\
  {a^2} - 3a =  - 12\,,\Delta  < 0\,and\,\,it\,hasn't\,real\,solutions. \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right. \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}
$$

Comment: That is neatly done. I was half looking out for how to convert this to a square and din't spot it.  I'll remember that one - a product of four consecutive integers is always one less than a square..

Answer (score 2):

If you just expand the multiplication and subtract the $5$ you get 
$$864 x^4 - 720 x^3 + 210 x^2 - 25 x -4=0$$
Then use the rational root theorem to find the roots $\frac 12, -\frac 1{12}$ and divide them out to get a quadratic with complex roots.

Answer (score 1):

**My advice for similar equations:** Multiply everything, move $5$ to the LHS and then factor the polynomial. The polynomial you obtain is, in this case, divisible by $x-\frac12$ and $x+\frac1{12}$.

Answer (score 1):

Given equation can be written as

$$(x-\frac{1}{12})(x-\frac{1}{6})(x-\frac{1}{4})(x-\frac{1}{3})=\frac{5}{24 \times 36}\tag 1$$

Let $$t=\frac{1}{4}(x-\frac{1}{12})+(x-\frac{1}{6})+(x-\frac{1}{4})+(x-\frac{1}{3})$$

So,  $y=x-\frac{5}{24} \tag 2$

Substituting $(2)$ in $(1)$ we get

$$(y+\frac{1}{24})(y-\frac{1}{24})(y+\frac{3}{24})(y-\frac{3}{24})=\frac{5}{24 \times 36}$$

Simplifying a little, and letting $$t^2-\left( \frac{5}{24}\right)^2=y$$

We get

$$(y+\frac{4}{242})(y-\frac{4}{242})=\frac{121}{1442}$$

$$y^2=\frac{16}{244}+\frac{121}{1442}$$

$$y=\frac{11}{144}$$

$$t= \pm \frac{7}{24}$$

Finally, we get $$ x=\frac 12 ; -\frac{1}{12}$$

Answer (score 1):

((12x-1)(3x-1))((6x-1)(4x-1))=5

$(36x^2-15x+1)(24x^2-10x+1)=5$

$12x^2-5=t$

(3t+1)(2t+1)=5

$6t^2+5t-4=0$

Answer (score 1):

So here is a way which turns out to make the solution obvious, but was intended just as a way of simplifying the arithmetic.

First multiply both sides by $2\times 3 \times 4 = 24$ to give $$(12x-1)(12x-2)(12x-3)(12x-4)=5\times 4\times 3\times 2=120$$

[Actually we could stop here, I notice - because we can match the product of four numbers on each side, but I wasn't that quick off the mark, for the other solution, now also obvious, write the product as $-2\times -3\times -4\times -5=120$]

---

Instead we can pursue my original train of thought on simplifying:

Now put $y=12x-3$ to give $$(y+2)(y+1)y(y-1)=(y^2+2y)(y^2-1)=y^4+2y^3-y^2-2y=120$$ so that $$y^4+2y^3-y^2-2y-120=0$$

Since we obtained $120$ as $5\times 4\times 3 \times 2$ in the first place, we see that $y=3$ is a solution and also $y=-4$ (taking the product of negative integers), and we can factorise to obtain the quadratic for the remaining roots.

Note that it is evident that as soon as $y\gt 1$ the product of four factors is positive and increases with $y$ and also for $y\lt -2$ the product is positive and increasing as $-y$ increases. It is also clear that for $-2\le y\le 1$ the product cannot be as large in magnitude as $120$ so there can only be two real roots, and we have found those.

---

Note: to factorise we can take the roots $y=3, y=-4$ and use the sum and product of the roots to determine the remaining factor as $$y^2+y+10$$ which is OK and has no real roots. But there is a neater way of doing the factorisation too.

---

Just to incorporate the neat observation of p.kn in one of the other answers - an observation for which I take no credit - $$(y+2)(y+1)y(y-1)=(y^2+y-2)(y^2+y)=(y^2+y-1)^2-1$$(difference of two squares).

This means that $$(y^2+y-1)^2=121$$and the problem spots into two quadratics $$y^2+y-1=11 \text { or }y^2+y-12=(y+4)(y-3)=0$$ and $$y^2+y-1=-11 \text { or }y^2+y+10=0$$which has no real solutions.

This is clearly the best way of factoring the equation (thanks p.kn) if you don't see the solution (as I didn't first off).

Comment: Actually this does more than simplify the arithmetic, as I first thought, it makes the solution obvious.

Comment: Note that the motivation here in the first place was simply to have all the factors with $12x$ in, and replace $12x$ with $y$ so that the numbers would be smaller when multiplying out the brackets. That could be a useful thing to do in any event with this kind of problem. Here there was a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

it can be simplified to $$ \left( 12\,x+1 \right)  \left( 2\,x-1 \right)  \left( 36\,{x}^{2}-15
\,x+4 \right) 
=0$$

Comment: How did you get both "12x- 1" and "6x- 1" to be equal to "t+ 1"?

Comment: this is a polynomial of degree $4$ and can be factorized in a product of two quadratic polynomials